# How to add different numbers at automatically added divs?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Im working on a confession website, and on the website I have a section "Top of the Week" which displays 3 most liked confessions from current week, it displays them in a horizontal slider by most liked order, so it goes most liked, second most liked, third most liked confession. The thing that Im trying to do is to put #1, #2, #3 number on each one, but I can't achieve that because I only style one div and website automatically create two other and add confession to it.

**This is my php + html code that I use to display them:**

```
<div class="sidebox">

<?php
$select = "SELECT confessions.confessId,
                                (IFNULL(confessions.firstName, '')) AS firstName,
                                confessions.confessText,
                                DATE_FORMAT(confessions.postDate,'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') AS postDate,
                                hasImage,
                                UNIX_TIMESTAMP(confessions.postDate) AS orderDate,
                                confessions.isActive,
                                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views WHERE views.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalViews,
                                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalLikes,
                                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dislikes WHERE dislikes.confessId = confessions.confessId ) as totalDislikes
                            FROM
                                confessions
                            WHERE isActive = 1
                            ORDER BY totalViews DESC , orderDate DESC limit 3";
                $resss = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select) or die('-3' . mysqli_error());  ?>

            <div id="sticky-nav" style="height:36px;" class="absolute" style="z-index:0">
        <div id="width-limit">
            <div class="options">
                <ul class="menu">
                            <li><a class="carousel_prev previous" href="#"><b style="font-size: 20px;">&#8249;</b></a></li>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<li><a style="opacity:1;padding-top:1px;position:relative;left:-54px;"><i class="fas fa-crown" id="crownicon"></i> Top of the Week</a>&nbsp;</li> 
                            <li><div class="menu-clear"></div></li> 
                            <li><a class="carousel_next next" href="#"><b style="font-size: 20px;">&#8250;</b></a></li>         
                        </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="options" id="opt2" style="float:right; width:280px;display:none;">
                <ul style="display: inline-block;float:right;">

                </ul>
            </div><div class="options" id="opt2" style="float:right; width:280px;display:none;">
                <ul style="display: inline-block;float:right;"> 
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="small-logo"></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        </div><div class="sidecontainer">
<div class="slick">
<?php
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resss)) {
                            // Get Total Comments
                            $comssql = "SELECT 'X' FROM comments WHERE confessId = ".$row['confessId']." AND isActive = 1";
                            $commentstotal = mysqli_query($mysqli, $comssql) or die('-4'.mysqli_error());
                            $totComments = mysqli_num_rows($commentstotal);
                            if ($totComments == '1') { $comText = 'Comment'; } else { $comText = 'Comments'; }
                            if ($row['totalViews'] == '1') { $viewText = 'View'; } else { $viewText = 'Views'; }
                            $shareURL = $set['installUrl'].'page.php?page=view&confession='.$row['confessId'];
                    ?>
                            <div class="confession" style="margin-left: 0;width: 300px;">
                                <div class="left"><span class="label2 label-confess1"><?php echo $row['totalViews'].' '.$viewText; ?></span></div>
                              <div class="right"><span class="bestthisweek">

                              <?php if ($row['totalLikes'] == '12') { echo "Top of the Day!"; } else { echo "Top!"; } ?>

                              </span></div>
                                <div class="confessionstyle" style="margin-top:20px;"><p> 
                                    <font color="#fff3b2">
                                    <?php
                                        if ($filterProfanity == '1') {
                                            echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars(filterwords($row['confessText'])));
                                        } else {
                                            echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row['confessText']));
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    </font>
                                    </p></div>
                                <input type="hidden" id="confessId" name="confessId_<?php echo $count; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>" />
                                <?php
                                    $chkLikes = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT 'X' FROM likes WHERE confessId = ".$row['confessId']." AND likeIp = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' LIMIT 1");
                                    $hasLike = mysqli_num_rows($chkLikes);

                                    $likeCSS = $hasLike > 0 ? 'text-info' : 'white';

                                    $chkDislikes = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT 'X' FROM dislikes WHERE confessId = ".$row['confessId']." AND dislikeIp = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' LIMIT 1");
                                    $hasDislike = mysqli_num_rows($chkDislikes);

                                    $dislikeCSS = $hasDislike > 0 ? 'text-danger' : 'white';
                                ?>
                                <div class="confession-actions">                                    
                                    <div class="likes" style="width: 75px;">
                                        <span class="label2 label-confess first liked">                                         
                                            <a href="" id="likeIt_<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>" class="likeIt_<?php echo $count; ?> <?php echo $likeCSS; ?>" style="text-decoration:none;outline:none;">
                                                <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> <span style="color:white;" id="likesVal_<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>"><?php echo $row['totalLikes']; ?></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </span>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="dislikes" style="width: 75px;">
                                        <span class="label2 label-confess disliked">
                                            <a href="" id="dislikeIt_<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>" class="dislike_<?php echo $count; ?> <?php echo $dislikeCSS; ?>" style="text-decoration:none;outline:none;">
                                                <span style="color:white;" id="dislikesVal_<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>"><?php echo $row['totalDislikes']; ?></span> <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>

                                    <?php if ($row['hasImage'] != '0') { ?>
                                        <span class="label label-confess"><i class="fa fa-picture-o img"></i></span>
                                    <?php } ?>

                                    <div class="comments">

                                        <div class="divide" style="width: 75px;"><div id="comments-hvr"><a href="page.php?page=view&confession=<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>">
                                            <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> <?php echo $totComments.' '; ?>
                                            </a></div></div>
                                    </div>

                                <div class="divide2" style="width: 75px;"><div class="fb-share-button" style="top:-6.5px;transform: scale(0.93);" 
    data-href="page.php?page=view&confession=<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>" 
    data-layout="button_count"></div></div></div>

                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                    <?php

                        }
                    ?>
               </div>
```

I tried everything and this is the best solution that I have, but I can't figure out what should I put inside `if, elseif, else`, I need something that will place #1 on first, #2 on second, #3 on third confession. So I would need something like this but something that will not require me to manually insert > likes.

```
<?php if ($row['totalLikes'] > '11') { echo "#1"; } elseif ($row['totalLikes'] > '5') { echo "#2"; } else { echo "#3"; }?>
```

Please visit my website, its still in development, but check Top of the Week on the right and you'll have a clue of what I actually want: http://confessions.byethost31.com

**FINAL:**

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>

    <?php

echo '#'.$i;
    $i++;

?>
```

Comment: This really confuses me. The code's a bit hard to read in a blob like this, but why are you comparing them to arbitrary numbers instead of each other? Isn't it possible that two confessions end up with the same number of likes, etc?

Comment: Sorry for the blob, this is example and what I came with, is there something that will make my number grom from 1 to 3 at each confession?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to to just create a variable that increments with every while iteration.

```
$i = 1; // set initial value     
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resss)) {
    echo 'This number will grow by 1 for every row - '.$i;
    $i++; // this is equal to $i = $i + 1; so will increment by 1 every time.
}
```

EDIT:

Instead of attempting to assume what the total likes would be, it would be easier to sort them by total likes (putting the most liked first and assigning this #1).

`ORDER BY totalLikes DESC, totalViews DESC, orderDate DESC`

You can then just use

```
echo '#'.$i;
```

Where you want to display the number, you can do this because you have LIMIT 3 so only the top 3 will display.

Comment: I reedit my main post please check it, am I doing something wrong? When I add it slider and confession is broken, thanks for help tho!

Comment: This wasn't code to insert, this was code to show you how to create a number the increments by 1.

Comment: Can you please check my code now, what I need to change?

Comment: I fixed it, thanks so much, ill edit how I got it there, you where really helpfull thanks! Just check if my code is good and does it require some changes?

Comment: You can do it that way :) As long as your ORDER BY is the correct way you want to order them.